# Basic Mysql Query Not working

Tags: mysql

I keep getting an error message with MySQL.  I have never messed with the command line and very much with it.  I am not sure where this error is stemming from.  See attached command prompt image:

Command line image

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste text into the question, these images are not complete

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Condition is a reserved word in MySQL. You can quote it with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO classfields (title, description, `condition`, ...)
VALUES (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`condition` is a reserved keyword. If you still want to use that as a column you should enclose that in quotes ``.

Here is the list of keywords: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html section 9.2